Swift package wrapping XCFramework as binaryTarget results in "multiple commands produce" for resource files present in both slices
I have a project based largely on swift packages. Every flow and dependency is its own package. This has worked well so far. However now I am in a situation where I have a dependency to a 3rd party XCFramework. I want to also wrap this in a swift package to "abstract" it away. This has gone well for other XCFrameworks, but for this one I run into issues.
I am adding the 3rd party sdk as a .binaryTarget of my wrapper package and adding the binary target as a dependency to my "main" target:
    let package = Package(
    name: "SomePackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SomePackage",
            targets: ["SomePackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SomePackage",
            dependencies: ["Some3rdPartyFramework"]),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "Some3rdPartyFramework",
            path: "Sources/Path/To/3rdPartySDK.xcframework"),
    ]
)

The issue is this XCFramework includes resource files, in this case some nib files as well as localizable.string files. These same resource files are included in both the device and simulator slice of the XCFramework and now the compiler complains that "multiple commands produce" the path for these resources. This is correct as the resource would end up in the same path regardless of whether I use the device or simulator slice of the XCFramework. However in reality these paths would never clash as I can never use both slices at the same time. It seems SPM does not know these slices would never co-exist and does not know how to handle this case.
The file structure of the XCFramework would be as follows:
- 3rdPartyFramework.xcframework
-- ios-arm64
--- some_view_controller.nib
-- ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
--- some_view_controller.nib

And I would get a "multiple commands produce" compile error for the path:
.../SomePackage.Bundle/some_view_controller.nib

Anyone have a solution to this issue?

can you share full error and probably a Package.swift file if it is needed. This error is usually shown when you have two files with the same name, and in the end of the error you can see which file is that.

HI @stackich, yes this is exactly the issue. However, as I mentioned, these files, that have the same name, they are placed in two different architecture slices of the XCFramework, I'll update my question to be more clear.
